# question about the choice of bandwidth in RDD

Tags: regression-discontinuity

I'm doing a research using the idea of regression discontinuity design. What confuses me is that whether I should choose a bandwidth if I use an IV approach to estimate in a fuzzy RD. I know that it's necessary to choose a proper bandwidth when doing local linear or polynomial regression but what about IV? 
It's my first time to ask questions here, nice to meet you all!
I'm looking forward to receiving your answers!